# Finnish-English Dictionary on Graph Theory and Reliability Engineering?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, reference-works, reliability

I need to translate an abstract to Finnish and I need to find a dictionary on Graph theory. Does there exist any canonical reference work in Finnish that could be used as a reference for finding the right vocabulary for English terms?

*Examples*

> 1. two-terminal network = kahden-terminaalin verkko vai [2-terminaalinen verkko](http://math.tut.fi/%7Eruohonen/GT.pdf)
> 2. terminal (vertex that cannot break in structural reliability engineering) = terminaali, [varma piste](http://math.tut.fi/%7Eruohonen/LT.pdf), varma komponentti
> 3. graph = graafi
> 4. network (graph with vertices and terminals) = verkko?
> 5. series-parallel graph = sarjaanrinnangraafi?
> 6. series-parallel system = sarjaanrinnansysteemi?
> 7. structural reliability theory = rakenteellinen luotettavuusteoria
> 8. sp-graph = sp -graafi
> 9. path graph = polkugraafi?
> 10. reliability = luotettavuus
> 11. parallel graph = rinnanverkko
> 12. $k$-out-of-$n$ system = $k$-$n$:stä -systeemi?
> 13. percolation event = percolation event

Comment: I would try to get hold of any material on graph theory in Finnish, books or maybe some slides on online?

Answer (score 1):

There are three different kinds of vocabulary in usage according to Prof. Keijo R. such that

> 1. **Network-theoretic vocabulary (Verkkoteoreettinen nimikkeistö)**: solmu (node), kaari (arc), silmä -- used in both Finnish and English, particularly in technical applications.
> 2. **Geometric vocabulary (Geometrinen, monitahokas-, nimikkeistö)**: kärki (vertex), särmä (edge), tahko (face) -- most vocabulary used in English, not in Finnish.
> 3. **Topological vocabulary (Topologinen eli käyräteoreettinen nimikkeistö)**: piste (point), viiva (line) -- more unusualy in English, used at least in Turku and Tampere in Finland.

---

The exact translations for terms such as series-parallel graph missing but I found the following, thanks to Prof. Matti P. for suggesting the book by Savolainen.

**Books**

1. Verkkoterian perusteet ja algoritmit (1978, Gaudeamus) by Vesa Savolainen has an appendix listing translation between Finnish and English
2. Verkkoteria (Docendro Finland) by Vesa Savolainen

**Online**

- [Graph theory in TUT](http://math.tut.fi/%7Eruohonen/GT.pdf) (looks like a book)
- [Gragh theory lecture notes](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/%7Empa/graaflu.pdf) in the University of Oulu
- [Minor Theory in Finnish](https://tampub.uta.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/79424/gradu02637.pdf?sequence=1) paper